# HTML Overlay in full screen using Video.js

Tags: video.js

Has anyone been able to create a full-screen overlay using Video.js player?  We are looking for a way to display a div over the video, and have it available even when in full-screen mode.

Comment: Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done on a recent project using JQuery UI dialogs, but the solution applies to whatever element you want to display over the video.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#overlay').dialog({
        width: $(window).width() * .8,
        height: 100,
        position: { my: "center", at: "bottom", of: window },
        autoOpen: false,
        zIndex: 2147483647
    });
});
int = setInterval(function(){checkNews()},checkNewsInterval);
function checkNews() {
    var url = 'news.php';
        $('#overlay').load(url, function() {
        $('#overlay').dialog('open');
        return false;
}
</script>
<body>
<div id="video-container">
    <video id="myvideo" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
    preload="auto"  poster="" data-setup="{}">
        <source src="<you_video_source>" type='video/mp4'></source>
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
    </video>
</div>
<div id="overlay"></div>
</body
</html>
```

The trick being the property:

```
zIndex: 2147483647
```

either set in the dialog setup or as a CSS in:

```
#overlay {
    z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me in Chrome. Any other solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The displaying of news over the video is a feature that we did not develop in production, so I stopped checking. FYI, the "magic" number is the highest value an integer can hold (2^31)-1. Try maybe an higher number?

Comment: I've just found the old test script and it still works on Chrome 31.0. Maybe your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I just tested a bit, and you need a z-index of `2147483647`. One lower and it won't display on top.